# Confused about __cdecl and __stdcall calling convention

Tags: c++, c

`__cdecl` calling convention says that：caller cleanup stack.

`__stdcall` calling convention says that: callee cleanup stack.

So i try to test code below:

```
#include <...>

char *callee()
{
    char str[] = "abcd";

    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char *str;
    str = callee();
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

According to the two calling convention above, I think:

`__cdecl` stack cleanup by caller, so `printf("%s\n", str)` should output "abcd".

`__stdcall` stack cleanup by callee, so `printf("%s\n", str)` should output messy chars.

But in fact, two all output messy chars. I am confused. Thanks for help!

Comment: `str` is on the stack, when `callee` is done, `str` is done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Clean up the stack" actually means "adjust the stack pointer so that it matches the changes done to stack pointer when arguments and return address were pushed onto stack". In your example it would be irrelevant who cleans up the stack - you would get the same undefined behavior, because you try to access a stack-allocated variable that is overwritten by a series of later pushes of arguments needed to perform `printf()`.

If you only write code in C or C++ you should not care of the exact details like "who cleans up the stack" - those details are critical only when writing in assembly. In C and C++ just be sure to mark function pointers with right calling conventions before calling a function through those pointers and the compiler will do the rest.

Comment: In the `main()` function, can I do something like this: `const char* &str = callee();`, that is bind a `const` reference to the return value of `callee()`?

Comment: @Alcott: No, since `callee()` returns a pointer which lifetime is in no way synchronized to the lifetime of the buffer it points to.

Comment: Do you that, the local variable `char str[] = "abcd";` is allocated on the stack, and when the `callee()` finishes, its stack is reclaimed, so `char str[]` vanishes?

Comment: @Alcott: Yes, it is allocated in automatic storage and when the function exits it goes out of scope and can no longer be legally accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Your error has no relation to calling convention. `callee()` is returning a pointer to a local variable, which is invalid as soon as `callee()` returns, and you get garbage data.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work the way you thought, because in both cases the stack pointer is adjusted between each function call. The difference is just who does it.

With the __stdcall convention, the stack pointer is adjusted (removing all parameters) just **before** the function returns to the caller. This saves code, as it is only done in one place.

With the __cdecl convention, the stack pointer is adjusted by the calling code, just **after** the return from the called function. If you have functions with a variable number of parameters, like printf, it is hard for it to remove the parameters as there can be a different number for each point of gtcall. Therefore, the calling function will have to do the adjustment. It will know how many parameters were actually passed.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is undefined in either case. Most probably, the call to `printf` will reuse the stack space previously used by `callee`.

Answer (score 0):

In the __cdecl case, the stack adjustment happens when the called function returns. By the time your printf executes the stack will have been adjusted.